# Euler.js Layout - Cytoscape

Tags: random, graph, cytoscape

I have deployed this layout to my application and is working fine, but I have two questions:

1. "Ramdomize" parameter must be always "true" so that the browser won't run into "Memory Out of Space" error. But, my question here is how can generate the same graph orientation very time when I launch my application?
2. Where can I find the graph state when generated and store it as the default layout so that users can see the same graph layout with the same position every time they launch the application.

Thank you very much.

Regards,

Arthur

Comment: This issue has been resolved by using local/session storage - storing the data at the browser.